# Layover at SFO for Dubai

Tags: international-travel, layovers, emirates, sfo, domestic

I’ll be traveling from Portland to SFO through Alaska. I have a layover of 1 hr 40 mins to fly to Dubai through Emirates. Both flights in one ticket through emirates.
Did some research and Alaska's arriving terminal is 2 and Emirates departure terminal is Terminal A. I see that we need to go through security checkpoint again.
Does anyone know if I will be getting boarding pass for Emirates airlines at Portland?
If no, should we exit Terminal 2 and go to Emirates counter for check in at SFO?
If anyone had experience with similar itinerary at SFO please provide some guidance

Answer (score -1):

That is an inconvenient connection.

Alaska is not a primary partner of Emirates, so you might not find out until you actually check in. You can try calling the airline ahead and ask.  If you do, you should also verify that your bags will be checked through.

You will have to go through security in SFO again anyway since there is no airside connection between Terminals 2 and A. See https://www.flysfo.com/passengers/travel-tips/international-travel/connections

Comment: Alaska is an interline partner of Emirates, and since the whole itinerary was booked as a single ticket, it would be very surprising if the luggage wasn’t checked through (it would probably be quite tight if it weren’t with only 1h40 layover time). In those cases all boarding passes are usually issued at once.

Comment: I am hoping to get boarding pass for emirates at once. Last time I had a layover at Seattle and Alaska did not give me a boarding pass for Seattle to Dubai. I am hoping that 1 hr 40 mins is enough to transit from Terminal 2 to A at SFO in case I need to collect a boarding pass from Emirates at their counter.

Comment: That's about a 15 minute walk. It's probably slightly faster to use the monorail "Airtrain" that connects the terminals. You want the Red line, two stops. This is all landside.

Comment: Thanks Andrew!! This will be helpful